# eigen matrix const type

Tags: c++, types, eigen

consider the following test

```
Eigen::MatrixXd B(Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(5,5));
const Eigen::MatrixXd C(Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(5,5));
std::cout << "B " << typeid(B).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << "C " << typeid(C).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << " === " << std::endl;
std::cout << "B.T " << typeid(B.transpose()).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << "C.T " << typeid(C.transpose()).name() << std::endl;
```

and its output

```
B N5Eigen6MatrixIdLin1ELin1ELi0ELin1ELin1EEE
C N5Eigen6MatrixIdLin1ELin1ELi0ELin1ELin1EEE
 === 
B.T N5Eigen9TransposeINS_6MatrixIdLin1ELin1ELi0ELin1ELin1EEEEE
C.T N5Eigen9TransposeIKNS_6MatrixIdLin1ELin1ELi0ELin1ELin1EEEEE
```

demangled

```
B Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>
C Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>
 === 
B.T Eigen::Transpose<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >
C.T Eigen::Transpose<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> const>
```

Why is `C` not shown as `const`? How does Eigen figure out it is? Is this an Eigen issue or is this `typeid` ?

Comment: Can you show us the mangled output?

Comment: I don't see what you can get out of that but why not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the behaviour of `typeid`:

> *§5.2.8/5 [expr.typeid]* The top-level cv-qualifiers of the glvalue expression or the *type-id* that is the operand of `typeid` are always ignored.

So in both cases, the `typeid` will only apply to `Eigen::MatrixXd`.

Comment: any idea why they added such a weird rule?